# What are the difference between achecker and w3c validator?

Tags: validation, accessibility, w3c

Sorry for this question. Anybody Can help me with some documentation or article about the difference between achecker and w3c validator?

Any info?

thanks
w.

Comment: One thing I can tell you is none o them is as good as FireEyes http://getfireeyes.com/ or aXe https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/axe-devtools/ (I am affiliated)

Answer (score 1):

W3C validator checks the markup validity of Web documents in HTML, XHTML, SMIL, MathML, etc. This tool checks the grammar of the document.

achecker is a basic tool to check a website according to WCAG recommendations (web content accessibility guidelines). As WCAG testing requires a lot of manual testing, and there is currently no good accessibility checker, those tools must be considered as indicators.